# WhatsApp Web doesn't generate QR code on Android phone's browsers

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, browser

[WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/%F0%9F%8C%90) doesn't generate a QR code when opened on Android phone's browsers.

I have already changed my settings to the desktop view, but still, the QR code is not generated.

How to show WhatsApp Web's QR code on Android phone's browsers?

Comment: Why would you want to use Whatsapp web on a phone?

Comment: The biggest issue is if you are looking to use WhatsApp Web on your primary device associated with your WhatsApp account, you will be unable to scan the QR code at any rate to validate.

Comment: @Firelord I assume OP wanted to mirror WhatsApp account on another Android device (which might make this an XY problem if that's the case) since according to [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/21009863/), you can only use 1 account on 1 device, if I didn't misinterpret it.

Comment: Dark themes in a browser may prevent the presented QR-code to be scanable by phones.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google Chrome for Android, then go to the menu, find the Desktop Site option, and see if it is already checked or not.

If not, then tap on it. It will be checked & show you the Desktop Version where you'll see the QR Code.

Comment: It works fine once, the qr code appears. When I close Chrome and reopen it going to web.whatsapp.com no qr code appears. After cleaning up Chrome all data, links, cookies, it works again, just once. Why?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't open WhatsApp Web on a phone as of now.

I have also tried many times before using many different browsers, but no go. Maybe in a later time, some new browser or setting can enable this.

Answer (score 0):

If in settings you clear ALL data of the Chrome app and restart Chrome, it works once. Obviously a cookie problem. Solution is to close all tabs, open a new incognito tab, check the Desktop site version from the menu, if not checked, open web.whatsapp.com et voila: the qr code.
Important is to open a NEW tab, when you exit from incognito Chrome deletes all cookies of it!